# How to architect token economies for DACs / DAOs built on EOS?

Tags: dapp, dac

From the keynotes and interviews of the Block.one team it is evident that they envision a world of Decentralized Autonomous Communities (DACs) and not just decentralized apps.

Steemit is the primary benchmark of such a community, where users don't buy-in (through an ICO) rather work-in to earn community tokens. Here's a good read about [The Next Stage in ICOs: The Community Token Economy](https://outlierventures.io/research/the-next-stage-in-icos-the-community-token-economy-cte/) by Outlier Ventures.

While EOSIO is making it easier to build decentralized apps, it is important to have an understanding of economics to autonomize (make it self sustaining) consumer facing apps.

Where can a beginner learn to architect a community token economy (like Steemit)? Are there resources/tools/templates online or people who we can collaborate with?

Answer (score 3):

On a recent [Epicenter](https://epicenter.tv/episode/232/) episode I heard Karl Floersch of the Ethereum Foundation was planning on teaching an [intro to cryptoeconomics](https://cryptoeconomics.study/) course.  Depending on what material he decides to cover in the course it might be useful for what you're trying to achieve.

There is also the [slockit](https://github.com/slockit/DAO) and [DAO](https://github.com/TheDAO/DAO-1.0) source code, which you could study to learn the basics.  While the DAO hack was related to poor implementation, the idea still remains a landmark in decentralized technology.

The [eosio.system](https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/tree/master/contracts/eosio.system) contracts are what will be used to vote for block producers.  There should be some really good code there for applying DAC concepts specifically to the eos.io blockchain.

Finally, the steem [source code](https://github.com/steemit/steem) is open source.